# Android Error running app: Default Activity not found

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

My program is giving me the following error in Android Studio.

00:28   Error running app: Default Activity not found

I think the problem is in the AndroidManifest.xml

`

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>
```

`
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

> Default Activity not found

Your application has no `<activity>` that will be launched by the home screen. That would need to have the appropriate `<intent-filter>`, such as:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
    <!-- This activity is the main entry, should appear in app launcher -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also:

- Attribute `parentActivityName` is only used in API level 16 and higher (current min is 15)`just means that your`android:parentActivityName` attribute will not have an effect on some devices that you are supporting
- However, `android:parentActivityName` is pointing to an activity (`MainActivity`) that does not exist in your manifest

Comment: Thank you. That has fixed the problem !

Answer (score 1):

To correct the

> android:parentActivityName is introduced in API 16

error, you should add this bloc of code for the activity that has a parent:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value="com.myapp.ui.MainActivity" />
```

Here is an example from one of my apps:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.souf.prayTime.ui.AboutActivity"
        android:label="@string/about"
        android:parentActivityName="com.souf.prayTime.ui.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.souf.prayTime.ui.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Hope this will help ;)

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to fix this is to increase your minimum API level to 16 so that it meets the requirements for 'parentActivityName'

To do this go into your build gradle.
Look for the minSdkVersion and change it to 16.

It's at the top in android{ defaultConfig {} }

Afterward Resync Gradle

Comment: Increasing the API level (and so reducing the app coverage) just to remove a warning does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: parentActivityName is API 16 and higher per Docs.  
https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/up-action

This is the best solution.  They can't use it if the version is not at least 16, so he MUST increase the min SDK if he wants to use it.  Otherwise he can choose not to use a Parent.